# How to find width required corresponding to NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, uilabel

This question has asked many times, however I have not clear, got wrong output. So please anyone help..

```
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(208, 21);
UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
CGSize myStringSize = [my_string sizeWithFont:myFont
                           constrainedToSize:maximumSize
                               lineBreakMode:self.my_label.lineBreakMode];
my_label.numberOfLines = 0;
my_label.frame.size = myStringSize;
```

I have a label of size (208, 21), I have used the following code to get actual height required for NSString with respect to my label width, I want fixed width, only height need to vary so I can set in label. But it always give lower height than actual.. Am I doing anything wrong here..

thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example use a maximum size with a (very) large height instead of restricting the height:

```
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(208, CGFLOAT_MAX);
```

This way there will always be enough height to expand to, while limiting the width to the width you actually want.

Comment: I have assigned the maximum size to the label size, but it is not resizing.. Any idea?

Comment: Don't assign the size to the label size, use it in the `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` method call. Just replace maximumSize in your example with my version.

Comment: This method will return an another size right..? Need to set that to my label?

Comment: Yes, that's what you're doing already in your example code. Replace the first line of your example with the line in my answer.

Comment: I have a problem... Size is coming fine.. but my label is not resizing with any value, I checked for null also. :(

Comment: Actually, the last line is not supposed to compile. You cannot update the size property directly, you have to set a new frame. `CGRect newFrame = my_label.frame; newFrame.size = myStringSize ; my_label.frame = newFrame;`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22742/discussion-between-newbee-and-joris-kluivers)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
-(CGSize) calculateWidthOfString:(NSString*)textString withFont:(UIFont*)font
    {
        CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(9999, 22);
        CGSize size = [textString sizeWithFont:font
                             constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
                                 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        return size;
    }
```

call this function with stringObject and Font Name, Size

it returns width of string with constant height "22" change this value as u want.

hope this will helps u.

Comment: @Joris Kluivers answer is better option if you want the constant width.

Answer (score 0):

```
+  (CGSize) calculateLabelHeightWith:(CGFloat)width text:(NSString*)textString
{
    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(width, 9999);
    CGSize size = [textString sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:24]
                         constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
                             lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return size;
}

+ (CGSize) calculateLabelWidthOfString:(NSString*)textString withFont:(UIFont*)font
{
    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(9999, 22);
    CGSize size = [textString sizeWithFont:font
                         constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
                             lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return size;
}
```

use these two for height or width